# C# EF add data to model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have those models

```
class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SimilarArtist> SimilarArtists { get; set; }   
}

class SimilarArtist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ArtistId")]
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public int Similar_Artist_Id { get; set; }
}
```

So each artist have links to other 5 from the same table. When the migration generate database it made that stracture.

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[LastName]
  FROM [dbo].[Artists]

SELECT [Id]
      ,[ArtistId]
      ,[Similar_Artist_Id]
  FROM [dbo].[SimilarArtists]
```

So when I do select the model it return this

```
var similar = _db.Artists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == id).SimilarArtists.FirstOrDefault();

//similar.ArtistId 
//similar.Id
//similar.Similar_Artist_Id
//similar.Artist //the object which return main artist
```

The question is how I can get in "var similar" not just Similar_Artist_Id but also name and lastname in the same request (without making requests by Similar_Artist_Id)

Answer (score 1):

```
var similarId = model.SimilarArtists.FirstOrDefault().Id;
var artiest = _db.Artists.Where(x.Id = similarId);
```

or just:

```
similar.Artist.Name
```

Or if you want to be able to have strongly-type property such as `similar.ArtistName`, create a `[NotMapped]` getter property.

```
class SimilarArtist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ArtistId")]
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public int Similar_Artist_Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ArtistName 
    {
       get 
       {
           return this.Artist.Name;            
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) it is more requests to database. sure i can do it but it is not a point
2) similar.Artist.Name return main artist name and it is the same for each 5

Comment: Artist object based on [ForeignKey("ArtistId")] and it return info which I alredy have -> main artist, but I need object based on Similar_Artist_Id. And it is the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var similar = _db.Artists.Where(x => x.Name == id)
              .Select(a => a.SimilarArtists.FirstOrDefault())
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives you the first `SimilarArtists` (with all of its properties)  of the first `Artists` matching the predicate `x.Name == id`.